# How to strip a url and get an unknown variable from a URL?

Tags: javascript, function, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I have several URLs that look like this:

http://domain.com/data/id/0000/random_title/

`domain.com/data/id/` <--- are a constant and never change

`/0000/` <--- I want to get this value (always 4 numbers)

`/title/` <-- this is different on every URL

What I need is a function that get the url from a row... analyze it(strip?)and create a new property with those 4 numbers..

I'm using Kimono to extract the data.... kimono allows the use of functions to modify the results and I found some examples but no documentation:

```html
function getpost_number(data) {
var post_number = 0;
for(var url in data.results) {
   data.results[url].forEach(function(row) {
    var parts = url.split("/");
    console.log(parts[5], parts[6]);
   });
  };
  data.post_number = post_number;
  return data;
}
```

Comment: `url.split('/')[5]` is the really simple answer ?

Comment: what does *"read url from row"* mean

Answer (score 0):

So either use split

```
var str = "http://domain.com/data/id/0000/random_title/",
    parts = str.split("/");
console.log(parts[5], parts[6]);
```

or a regular expression

```
var str = "http://domain.com/data/id/0000/random_title/",
    match = str.match(/http:\/\/domain.com\/data\/id\/(\d{4})\/([^\/]+)\//);
console.log(match[1], match[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @epascarello I used your code and I receive a error: "Unexpected token function" the code I'm using is:

function getpost_number(data) {
var post_number = 0;
for(var url in data.results) {
   data.results[url].forEach(function(row) {
    var parts = url.split("/");
    console.log(parts[5], parts[6]);
   });
  };
  data.post_number = post_number;
  return data;
}

Comment: Why do you have a forEach?? Code does not make any sense when I have no idea what you are looping over...

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

```
    function getpost_number(data) { 
        var post_number = 0; 
        for(var url in data.results) { 
            data.results[url].forEach(function(row) { 
                // Here you need use "row" not "url"
                var parts = row.split("/"); 
                console.log(parts[5]+parts[6]); 
            }); 
        }; 
        data.post_number = post_number; 
        return data; 
    }
```